# finding email with preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have this code to find email addresses in given text:

```
preg_match_all("|[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z]+|",
"</b>a@bexample </b> a@bexample.co ",$out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

And the output is like this:

```
   Array
       (
       [0] => Array
           (
                [0] => a@bexample//error one
                [1] => a@bexample.co
           )

   )
```

the first answer isn't true. why?

Comment: Because is not a valid email, needs domain (the part after the `.`)

Comment: Try to use this regular expression: "/[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}\b/i"

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot the "\" before "." it should be like this

```
"|[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+|"
```

Comment: You are missing addresses in subdomains (many ccTLDs like .uk have mandatory second levels, and there are deep hierarchies like k12.us). You are ignoring email addresses containing plus, apostrophe, percent sign, and a number of other permitted characters (mine contains a plus, and many services, including Gmail, allow a plussed suffix to your main address as a useful feature). See the linked question in @Ilya's comment for lots more to think about.